# Use foreign key as part of composite key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

So, I'm creating this app that's sort of like Google Analytics. The user installs the JS snipped on his blog and the JS sends metrics related to each post. The only extra information needed to install it's his `site_id` (sort of like the google analytics id). This app is going to only work with wordpress, and for each blog post an entry in the `posts` table will be created, so I have the following migration:

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
   create_table :posts, primary_key: %i[id site_id] do |t|
      t.belongs_to :site, null: false
      t.bigint :id
      t.bigint :post_id
      t.string :url

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I've created this composite key which the foreign key (`site_id`) is part of it. I would like to know if this is ok, and if it would break any aspect of ActiveRecord.

I know it might look like a weird thing, so let me explain why I need this.

The `id` of the posts is going to be the same id used in the wordpress blog post database, so let's say I have two users, each one with one site and each one containing 5 posts. If their blog posts contain the same `id`, this would be a problem... but if I have a composite key `site_id` + `post_id` it's ok. My only concern is if this could break how ActiveRecord handle associations.

I'm making some tests and everything seems to be working, but I'm not sure, because although creating a post works, this warning keeps showing up:

```
WARNING: Active Record does not support composite primary key.

posts has composite primary key. Composite primary key is ignored.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

So, Rails ActiveRecord does not support composite primary keys by default. This the reason you'll be seeing this message ([here is the source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/primary_key.rb#L122))

However, if you want to use this feature, you can try [composite_primary_keys](https://github.com/composite-primary-keys/composite_primary_keys) gem

So you can do something like

```rb
# after installing the gem
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_keys = :id, site_id
  ...
end
```

Comment: I heard I could also use add_index. Is that correct?